# javascript doesn't work on content created from infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am building a Facebook like page, an infinite long page, where new posts keep loading as you scroll more and more.

to make the comment textarea grow with text I'm using

```
$('.comment-textarea').autosize();
```

And to submit the comment on enter I'm using

```
$('.comment-textarea').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey){

    } else if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.comment-form').trigger('submit');
    }

});
```

These code works flawlessly for contents that are loaded when you open my website. But it doesn't work on the contents that come because of Infinite scrolling facility on my website. After research a lot I only got to know about Event delegation http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ but I am not sure if it applies to my case cause I've tried to use it and it didn't help.

for infinite scrolling, i am following this tutorial
http://miftyisbored.com/wp-tutorials/cakephp-infinite-scroll/

and using this jquery plugin https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Sorry, I forgot to mention that for autosize() method I am using
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

**Solution**
anybody looking for a solution to such problem, look at *dm4web* answer and use

```
$('.comment-textarea').autosize();
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.comment-textarea').autosize();
});
```

code to make autosize() work with infinite scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$('body').on('keypress','.comment-textarea',function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey){

    } else if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.comment-form').trigger('submit');

    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/et2p2oyv/

EDIT 2:

after append call again $('.comment-textarea').autosize();

http://jsfiddle.net/et2p2oyv/1/

Comment: can you please help me this too, `$('.comment-textarea').autosize();` ?

Comment: nah, that not working. still getting the same effect.
autosize() works for elements which are loaded before scrolling and doesn't work for element which come up after scrolling.

Comment: each time after scrolling call $('.comment-textarea').autosize();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('keypress','.comment-textarea', function(e){
     if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey){

    } else if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.comment-form').trigger('submit');
    }

});
```

This doesn't work too?

Comment: omg, that worked. :)
can you please tell me how would do that for autosize too

Comment: check my edit on original post about autosize() method.